# Unexpected token '<' at Loader.moduleStrategy

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, pm2

I'm running a backend Express app and a React.JS app in one Docker container using PM2. My backend Nodejs Express app works fine, it's just the React app.

I had an initial error of: `Cannot use import statement outside a module` which I was able to fix by adding: `"type": "module"` to my `package.json` file. Which fixed that error but now I'm getting a new error of: `Unexpected token '<'  at Loader.moduleStrategy` I'm assuming it's an `ESLINT` error. I'm using JavaScript, not TypeScript.

I have tried to install `"babel-preset-react"` as that apparently fixes this new error after a Google Search, but it did not work.